# Trying to convert a cftree to be used in Flex project.

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, coldfusion, mxml

Flex noob here. I have an old ColdFusion page that I need to convert for a Flex project and I wondered if any one had any advice or resources they recommend for doing this? I just need the following code to work in a mxml page (and/or action-script page if necessary.)

```
<cfform name="theForm" height="100%"  width="100%" timeout="#Application.formTimeout#" format="flash" skin="haloblue" wmode="transparent" 
action="" onload="formOnLoad();#selectText#" >
<cfinclude template="/includes/generalFunctions.cfm">
<cfformitem type="script">

    <cfinclude template="/includes/as/filter.as">
    <!--- Function runs onload --->
    function formOnLoad() {

        <!--- Adjust the screen size --->
        adjustScreenSize(mainContainer,theForm);
    }
</cfformitem>
<cfformgroup id="mainContainer" type="panel" height="440" width="700" style="#panelStyle#" label="Months End Reports">
    <cfformitem type="text" style="text-align:center;#textHeaderStyle#">Months End Reports List</cfformitem>
    <cfformitem type="text" style="text-align:center;#textStyle#">Click on the file below to display the report!</cfformitem>
    <cfformgroup type="horizontal" style="horizontal-align:center;">
        <cftree     name="MonthsEndReport"
                    format="flash"
                    height="300"
                    width = "400" 
                    font="Verdana"
                    highlighthref="No"
                    HScroll="no"
                    VScroll="no"
                    completepath="no"
                    lookandfeel="windows"
                    required="yes"
                    appendkey="no"> 
                <cfoutput group="reportType" query="finalResult">
                    <cftreeitem value="#ReportType#" parent="MonthsEndReport" expand="yes">
                        <cfoutput>
                            <cftreeitem
                                value=""
                                display="#Name#"
                                parent="#reportType#"
                                img="document"
                                target="_blank"
                                href="sample.cfm?template=#test#.html">
                        </cfoutput>
                </cfoutput>
        </cftree>

    </cfformgroup>
</cfformgroup>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So, what have you tried?  Why didn't it work?  What does this code do? Unfortunately, "Flex Forms" were built with Flex 1.5; so you're probably stuck re-creating this functionality from scratch.  You can probably use the Tree component to replace cftree, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: I honestly didn't try much, but now that I know there is a Tree function in Flex, that was a perfect place to start. I was so focused on converting it, that I didn't find that on Google. I now have the tree function in Flex but I'm still working on linking the dataprovider to my CF query results. Hopefully it will look ok.